# Broken cell with an odd strikethrough?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having a weird issue with a particular UITableView in my iPhone devel experience here. If you look at the following screenshot:

[alt text http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/57676/brokencell.png](http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/57676/brokencell.png)

you'll notice a strike through going through the middle of the 'Jane Aba' cell.

Any idea what might be causing this odd graphic display? It's true for both the simulator and for the actual device running 2.2 SDK.

As requested, here's my `-tableView:cellForRowIndexPath:` method:

*** EDIT ***

I've located the problem. I'm not entirely sure why this is the problem, but it is. In my RootViewController, I have the following line of code in my `-initWithCoder:` method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

When I comment that out, the cell (which is not in the RootViewController, but a secondary controller) it's resolved. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Are these standard UITableViewCell cells, or subclasses? Does the line move when you scroll the table? Is it in EVERY cell, or just one of them?

Comment: Hi Ben, these are standard UITableViewCell cells. I haven't done any subclassing for complex cells. The line does move with the cell and it's only in one cell, for Jane Aba. My other fictitious characters do not have the strike through.

Comment: have you added any subviews to the table? Are you using custom table row heights?

Comment: None to the above, unfortunately. Nothing custom, no additional subViews.

Comment: Also, it happens with SDK 2.1. So this isn't a 2.2. bug.

Comment: Show us the code you're using in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and also how you're setting the accessory view.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. For me, the single line was caused by a superfluous view that was created but never sized or placed correctly and so was 1 pixel high, floating over everything else. You can also cause this by confusing a UINavigationController about its set of subviews (by adding views directly to its layout container).

Look through your UI (xib files and programmatically created views) for a view that shouldn't be there or is otherwise not being used. It might be helpful to write some code to dump a UI Hierarchy, so you can see what views are where.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything special in your -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method?

It looks to me like the height of the row is being set incorrectly, so the contents of the cell are expanding outside of its bounds.

Comment: Haven't added that method, so nope. Makes sense though if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappears when you set the cell height for the table view to 1 pixel in IB. It seems that before you populate the table, an empty table is drawn with the outlines of the cell height set in IB.
Don't set the cell height to 0. IB doesn't like that. :-)